# If a directory is put in lost+found after running fsck, will it contain all of the original contents?

Tags: ext4, fsck, lost-found

Let's say I have the following directory structure, in an ext4 filesystem:

a/b/{1..9}

(in other words, a/b/1, a/b/2, ... a/b/9)

Suppose I am writing to a/b, and then I lose power. fsck runs and finds some files (a/b/1, a/b/2, etc.) and puts them in lost+found.

Now, the question is, would all of the missing files that were placed in lost+found be under the same directory? So for example if every file 1-9 was lost, is it guaranteed that lost+found would contain something like:
lost+found/#1234567/*, where the folder #1234567 contains all the files 1-9? Or is it possible for them to be spread out into separate directories like:
lost+found/#1234567/1, lost+found/#7654321/2, etc.?

I'm asking because I am trying to understand how I might go about systematically recovering a specific folder that was lost, and whether they would already be grouped together in lost+found, or whether I would have to check every existing file in lost+found to find the missing pieces.

Comment: Can you clarify your question by giving a specific filesystem type or, if this is an assignment, adding the complete text to the question? The answer also depends on whether only a or only b or both have been corrupted.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick this isn't an assignment, this is just a general question about filesystem behavior. I'll edit the question, thanks!

Comment: @MarkPlotnick also I'm really not sure which of the directories got corrupted - could you explain the various scenarios? Is there any situation in which they would not be located together?

Answer (score 2):

Inodes are put into `lost+found/` when there is no directory entry referencing them, so there is no "name" for the inode.  If the parent directory (`a/` in this case) was lost/corrupted (either the inode itself, or the directory block(s) that hold the name-to-inode mapping for each file/directory therein), then it is likely inode `b/` would be put into `lost+found/` with the name `#inode_number`.  If `b/` itself is not corrupted then all of the entries (`1..9`) would still be inside, and you could rename `#inode_number` out of `lost+found/` back to where it came from.

That said, if `a/` and `b/` were created at nearly the same time, they will likely be physically close together on disk, so it is possible they might both be corrupted at the same time.

If `b/` is corrupted, then the files therein will be individually put into `lost+found/` and they will need to be identified by UID/GID and/or content.